# XMLRAD.Projects.xml copy file error when running XMLRAD

Tags: sourceforge

I freshly unpack and run XMLRAD from XMLRAD.org (stable release), but still get this error:

```
  The specified file or path was not found : Cannot copy file C:\Delos\xmlrad\Bin\Data\XMLRAD.Projects.xml to C:\Delos\xmlrad\Data\XMLRAD.Projects.xml
```

The same if I try to change install folder location or run as console or service... Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You raised a very interesting showstopper in the build,
I have been able to reproduce and locate the problem,
I am submitting a patch,
a new stable build will be available shortly,

your feedback is very valuable.

Comment: Your submit fix my problem, thanks a lot! Let's go building my first app! ;)

Comment: Is there a way to create a new project ?

Comment: You hack on an existing project such as demo "Ultima" (duplicate it if necessary to start a new project)